# Owin multi path in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have class for Owin like this

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{


    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/members/Login")

    });
}
```

Then i have another link like `/distributor/Login`

When i go to home distributor without login it is always redirect to `members/login`

How can i config i need to redirect to `/distributor/login`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try [CookieAuthenticationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationprovider(v=vs.113).aspx), but I've not tested your scenario

Setting `LoginPath = null` [CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.loginpath(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = null,
   Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { 
  OnApplyRedirect =  (context) =>
 {
   Uri defaultURI = Url.Action("Login", "members"); 
 //check for distributor in the request uri
 //Modify logic appropriately
 if(context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("distributor"))
 {
  defaultURI = Url.Action("login", "distributor"); ;
  }

context.RedirectUri = defaultURI;
originalHandler.Invoke(context);
 };

});
```